# How to get MX Player to show .gif files in file lists?

Tags: video, file-management, media-files, mx-player

[MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro) is able to play .gif files, but does not populate its list views (i.e., internal file explorer) with them, even when explicitly defined as an extension through the relevant settings page (it accepts the change and refreshes with no error message, but nothing new loads on the front end and going back in reveals the added entry does not persist).  The only way to play them is by opening through another app `as video`, and then selecting MX Player.  I've reached out to the dev team but they have advised that as far as they are concerned, this behavior is in line with their expectations according to their categorical interpretation of the .gif file extension not qualifying as a "video" media file container (a distinction I fail to comprehend, much less concur with).  In any case, I'd like to see if there's any method to take matters into my own hands, e.g., any .cfg files or similar preference store that can be modified directly to "force" persistent recognition and enumeration of the file extension?

Comment: I would recommend to ask questions about MX Player as suggested in the app description on XDA: on http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/mx-player or Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/MXPlayer

Comment: If the developer didn't mention any solution/workaround, then it's unlikely there's any configurable setting that can be modified by the end-user. Looks like it's the logic in the app, which means that it needs to be modified and built from the source code (or reverse-engineer and modding, but that's outside of the scope of this site).